# Swing - Native look-and-feel for JDialog in MacOS

Tags: java, macos, swing, look-and-feel

Does `Swing` support native dialog like below:
[image]

Or maybe exists some third party's `JNI` library?

Comment: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/lordy/archive/2006/08/mustang_and_mac.html - samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but [*Java on OS X v10.5 Update 1*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/JavaLeopardUpdate1RN/Introduction/Introduction.html) says, "*Document Modal Sheets* can be created by setting the the `apple.awt.documentModalSheet` client property to `Boolean.TRUE` on the `JRootPane` of `JDialog`." I'm guessing something like this:

```
rootPanel.putClientProperty("apple.awt.documentModalSheet", Boolean.TRUE);
```

You might also see if [*Mac Widgets for Java*](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/) has added anything recently.

Comment: The system property "apple.awt.documentModalSheet" is mis-named. What it creates is a document-modal utility pane.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of a Swing look and feel called [VAqua](https://violetlib.org/vaqua/clientlibrary.html), which supports displaying windows as native sheets using an associated client library.

For example:

```
    JFrame owner = ...;
    JWindow w = new JWindow(owner);
    try {
        VSheet.displayAsSheet(w, null);
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException ex) {
        ...
    }
```

Details [here](https://violetlib.org/vaqua/sheets.html).